# How can I save videos to the Photo Album with specific name

Tags: ios5, alassetslibrary

When I try to save video by ALAssetLibrary method writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum the video's will be saved by name which will generated by AssetLibrary e.g. IMG_0111, IMG_0123 etc. How can I save these video's by specific name like "myAppName1.mov"
Following is the code snippet.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:tempURL
                            completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
 {
     if(error)
     {
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Saved video at %@\n", [assetURL path]);
     }
 }];
[library release], library = nil;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to achieve this at the moment. You can't specify a file name, the Photolibrary assigns as you described filenames conforming to the pattern "IMG_XXX.ext" automatically. 
The only case, when the file name is preserved is when photos get imported through the camera connection kit.

Cheers,

Hendrik